# What goes into Belloq's mouth exactly? Is this a mistake, a joke on purpose, or something more?

Tags: plot-explanation, indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

In *Raiders Of The Lost Ark*, when Jones has the bazooka pointed to the Ark and shouts something, Belloq turns around and there's a moment in which you can see an ant or something going into Belloq's mouth.

What is it that goes into his mouth exactly? Is this a mistake, a joke on purpose, or something more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a **fly** BUT, in fact, it doesn't actually go into his mouth.

Apparently, according to Paul Freeman who played Belloq a few frames were cut out of the movie where the fly actually flew away.

> Q: Can you tell us something about that, and working with the most famous fly in the world?
>
> PF: Ah, yes. I don’t think anybody noticed it during the shoot, there wasn’t any hilarity at that point in the film, and I think if you look at it carefully, if you freeze the frame around that point, you’ll see that actually some frames are missing.
>
> Q: Yeah, I think I noticed that, just a little too jerky.
>
> PF: Yeah, **I think they just took out a couple of frames when the fly flew off**, just to make the joke. I got a very nice review from Pauline Kayland who noted what a devoted actor I was to go through it, with eating the fly and all.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.thebeardedtrio.com/2016/03/did-paul-freeman-accidentally-eat-fly.html) and [**Source**](http://www.theindyexperience.com/interviews/paul_freeman_interview.php)</sup>